# Create your own tfds.load

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is what I have

```
# Ratings data.
ratings = tfds.load('movie_lens/100k-ratings', split="train")
# Features of all the available movies.
movies = tfds.load('movie_lens/100k-movies', split="train")

# Select the basic features.
ratings = ratings.map(lambda x: {
    "movie_title": x["movie_title"],
    "user_id": x["user_id"]
})
movies = movies.map(lambda x: x["movie_title"])
```

Since I don't want to download `MovieLens`, but my own data set. I tried reading it through `pandas`. Unfortunately, a `data frame` does not have a `map(...)` method. Is there an option that reads my .csv file and transfers it like `tfds.load(...)`

This is what I tried

```
# Ratings data.
ratings = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Dataset/Test/ratings.csv')
movies = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Dataset/Test/movies.csv')
```

The Error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Comment: Hi @Marcel.david1, Can you tell me what you want to achieve, so I can suggest a better alternative.

Comment: @Tfer3 thank you for your comment! I want to use the TensorFlow Recommenders https://github.com/tensorflow/recommenders but with my own Dataset. 
Do not hesitate contacting me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need your own `tfds.load`, it simply returns a `tf.data.Dataset` object, which you can easily build yourself. E.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwas'
                 'kom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(df)).\
    map(lambda x: x['sepal_width']).\
    batch(4)

next(iter(ds))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([3.5, 3. , 3.2, 3.1])>
```

Coming from the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview):

> Note: Do not confuse TFDS (this library) with tf.data (TensorFlow API to build efficient data pipelines). TFDS is a high level wrapper around tf.data. If you're not familiar with this API, we encourage you to read the official tf.data guide first.

Read more about [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset).

Here's how you can use it in a learning task:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwas'
                 'kom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')

labels = ['versicolor', 'setosa', 'virginica']

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    df.drop('species', axis=1).values, df['species'].values)).\
    shuffle(150).\
    map(lambda x, y: (x, tf.where(tf.equal(labels, y))[0])).\
    batch(4)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')])

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(ds, epochs=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the `map` method on `pandas.Dataframe` object, but the `map` is applied to `pandas.Series` object.

You can convert your `dataframe` to `tf.data.Dataset` object and then you can apply the `map()` function like `tfds` dataset.

Below is the sample example with sample data to convert from `dataframe` object to `tf.data` object.

```
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'feature1': np.random.rand(10),
        'feature2': np.random.rand(10),
        'feature3': np.random.rand(10),
        'target': np.random.randint(0, 3, 10)
    }
)
features = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3'] 

dataset = (
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (
            tf.cast(df[features].values, tf.float32),
            tf.cast(df['target'].values, tf.int32)
        )
    )
)
```